# Using data files not incorporated inside my app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8.1

I have an API I built and warpped it into a CoCa Framework (iOS 8) My API engine is using a few big data files. (~100MB)

My problem is the engine is optional. My end user may or may not want to have that feature. So, I don't want to include these files inside my library (framework). I want to be able to download it on user request and then use it.

What is the BKM for making this framework (and app) in a normal size, and then download the 100MB only on user's request?

Everywhere I go it seems like the talk is around Static Libraries and how everything should be included in advance inside the app package.

What, if any, are the alternatives?

Sorry If I miss the obvious...

Comment: Are part of the files static data or images? If so you can download them. What is not allowed is code for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you data files don't contain executable code, you can store them elsewhere. If it's in-app purchase content, you can store these files on Apple servers.

From the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW9):

> If the product has associated content, your app needs to deliver that
>   content to the user. For example, purchasing a level in a game
>   requires delivering the files that define that level, and purchasing
>   additional instruments in a music app requires delivering the sound
>   files needed to let the user play those instruments.
>
> You can embed that content in your app’s bundle or you can download it
>   as needed—each approach has its advantages and disadvantages. If you
>   include too little content in your app bundle, the user must wait for
>   even small purchases to be downloaded. If you include too much in your
>   app bundle, the initial download of the app takes too long, and the
>   space is wasted for users who don’t purchase the corresponding
>   products. Additionally, if your app is too large, users won’t be able
>   to download it over cellular networks.
>
> Embed smaller files (up to a few megabytes) in your app, especially if
>   you expect most users to buy that product. Content in your app bundle
>   can be made available immediately when the user purchases it. However,
>   to add or update content in your app bundle, you have to submit an
>   updated version of your app.
>
> Download larger files when needed. Separating content from your app
>   bundle keeps your app’s initial download small. For example, a game
>   can include the first level in its app bundle and let users download
>   the rest of the levels when they’re purchased. Assuming your app
>   fetches its list of product identifiers from your server, and not
>   hard-coded in the app bundle, you don’t need to resubmit your app to
>   add or update content that is downloaded by your app.
>
> In iOS 6 and later, most apps should use Apple-hosted content for
>   downloaded files. You create an Apple-hosted content bundle using the
>   In-App Purchase Content target in Xcode and submit it to iTunes
>   Connect. When you host content on Apple’s servers you don’t need to
>   provide any servers—your app’s content is stored by Apple using the
>   same infrastructure that supports other large-scale operations, such
>   as the App Store. Additionally, Apple-hosted content automatically
>   downloads in the background even if your app isn’t running.
>
> You might choose to host your own content if you already have server
>   infrastructure, if you need to support older versions of iOS, or if
>   you share your server infrastructure across multiple platforms.